# How to insert new lines after a specific empty line in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk

I'm trying to find a way to insert a new line after a specific empty line.
for example I have a file contains firewall rules, and I want to insert new lines after "`# ok icmp code for FORWARD`" and first empty line. (I don't know the exact line number and it is different in multiple machines):

```
...

# ok icmp code for FORWARD
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

[Insert new lines here]
# new lines comment
new line 1
new line 2

...
```

here is my incomplete solution:
to find the specific line number:

```
cat file.rules | grep -n "ok icmp code for FORWARD" | cut -d':' -f 1
```

to show the lines after specific line and before the empty line:

```
awk '!NF{f=0} /ok icmp code for FORWARD/ {f=1} f' file.rules
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ed` to edit the file:

```sh
ed -s file.rules <<'EOF'
/^# ok icmp code for FORWARD/;/^$/a
# new lines comment
new line 1
new line 2
.
w
EOF
```

First sets the current line to the one matching `# ok icmp code for FORWARD`, then advances the current line to the first blank line following that, and **a**ppends text after it (A line with a single period marks the end of input), then **w**rites the changed file back to disk.

Comment: Thank you. Can I read a user input with this solution? I'm using 'read ip_network' in my script to receive the input from user and I want to call that in inserted line.  ($ip_network). but it doesn't work in this case. this is the line had been inserted: -A ufw-before-forward -d $ipv4_network/24 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Sure; just use the version of a heredoc that does parameter expansion, and remember to escape the $ in the regex.

Comment: Thanks. I just removed quotes in 'EOF' and calling the variable worked.